# Iterate all possible results of add subtract 6 float variables

Tags: java

Stuck here and hope this is easy for someone with the right experience.

I'm trying to find a way to calculate all combinations of 6 float variables. Add, subtract, and zero.  I can do this with a massive switch/case statement but expect there must be some more intelligent approach to this problem.

A set of nested for loops? Recursion? Put the 6 vars into an array and have a second method to add,subtract,zero?

I prefer to avoid using any matrix or collection libraries and just do in pure Java. Example of what I mean:

```
public int mixVars6(int selector, float A, float B, float C, float D, float E, float F) {

    switch (selector) {
        case 0:
            return Math.round(A - B - C - D - E - F);
        case 1:
            return Math.round(A - B - C - D - E + F);
        case 2:
            return Math.round(A - B - C - D - E + 0);  // exclude F
        // continues so that each variation of + and - is covered
        case xx:   // more complex example:
            return Math.round(A + B + C - D - E + F);
    }
 }
```

EDIT: In response to comments: It is not a school project. I'm trying to find out a combination of leading, top, bottom, ascent, decent variations on a TrueType font rendering problem I'm having.  Some of the values are negative and position I can't find the desired combination using proper methods. I'm trying to  find a way to iterate all the variations of these variables. The selector is tied to a hardware button and I'm visually reviewing the layout changes as I increment it +1.

EDIT: I think there is probably a way to do this with 3 nested for loops that modulus the selector? The operator can be expressed this way:

```
    // Addition, subtraction, and zero can be achieved by multiplication
    float[] operators = { 1f, -1f, 0f };
```

Thank you

Comment: What does "try" mean? What is the end result you're expecting?

Comment: I am not sure if I get your question. Do you also want to compute, say `A+B-C+D-E+F'?

Comment: It seems that he wants to compute every combination of add or substract for all 6 values? I guess that means every combination like 'A+B-C-D-E+F' or 'A-B-C+D+E-F', etc.

Comment: Yes, every combination. So we are talking 18 selector possibilities? or 36 - as I should probably negate the A variable also....

Answer (score 0):

You need a recursive function, whose header looks like

```
public static void combineFloats(float[] floats, float currentSum, int idx)
```

Where the float array contains all of your numbers, and in the initial call, currentSum is 0, and idx = 0, with idx getting bigger by 1 every time you descend recursively

Comment: The signature of a method doesn't answer his question. And why exactly do you think that such a method must be static?

Comment: @Jägermeister I have added more explanation on how it should be coded. Since this is likely a school project, it's appropriate to give a clue rather than the answer. `static` is also appropriate, since the method is stateless

Answer (score 0):

Here is the idea (I will leave the implementation for you):

For 6 variables there will be 5 operators. If we represent "-" as 0 and "+" as 1 then all possible combinations of operators will be represented by numbers from 00000 to 11111 which is from 0 to 31.

0 -> 00000 -> A-B-C-D-E-F

1 -> 00001 -> A-B-C-D-E+F

.....

31 -> 11111 -> A+B+C+D+E+F

How about 0? You just need to go through all 31 combinations above and replace each var at each position with 0.

So the algorithm is:

For each number from 0 to 31

- Convert the number to binary and append to make enough 5 digits
- Extract 5 digits from generated binary
- For each 0 replace with -, for each 1 replaces with + and form the expression
- For each position replace the variables with 0

Comment: That's pretty much what the switch/case is doing already... having a unique line for each variation.

Comment: @RoundSparrowhilltx, Who says you have to use switch. See the explanation above.

Answer (score 0):

There are 5 positions where +/- can be added(let's not consider the case of 0's at the moment), there will be 32 combinations(2^5).

Now for each of 32 combinations, we can start applying that "0" condition, again with the similar procedure, since there are 6 digits(A,B,C,D,E,F), the combinations would be 64(2^6).

Now the biggest problem is: How to iterate through those permutations:
Simple, binary counting would help.

Example: Suppose,

00000 represents all symbols are plus.

00001 would represent all symbols are plus but last one is minus

and so on

Similarly, 0's can mean that the digit at that position has to be taken and 1 would mean that it shouldn't be taken.

you will just need a for loop which would do binary counting upto 5 digits, and inside it another for loop which would do binary counting upto 6 digits, and handle the rest of your code(arrays or whatever) accordingly.